# Extreme values of function w/ rational power

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the extreme value of the following function (in terms of $z$),
where $a$ is some positive real number:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\left(a+(z+a)^2\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{\left(a+(z-a)^2\right)^{3/2}}$$

I have tried to find the root of its derivative:
$$f'(z)=\frac{-3(z+a)}{\left(a+(z+a)^2\right)^{5/2}}-\frac{-3(z-a)}{\left(a+(z-a)^2\right)^{5/2}}$$
$$0=\frac{-3(z+a)}{\left(a+(z+a)^2\right)^{5/2}}-\frac{-3(z-a)}{\left(a+(z-a)^2\right)^{5/2}}$$
$$\frac{z+a}{\left(a+(z+a)^2\right)^{5/2}}=\frac{z-a}{\left(a+(z-a)^2\right)^{5/2}}$$
I'm not sure how to proceed after this.

Graphically, I can see that the function is odd, with a minima at some positive $z$ and a maxima at some negative $z$ (extrema points are equidistant from 0).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Might need a correction. Aren't the terms the same on either side of the minus sign in the first expression?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Had a typo

Comment: You mean, the function (i.e. $f$) is **odd**, not even.  That's because changing $z$ to $-z$ interchanges $1/(a+(z+a)^2)^{3/2}$ and $1/(a + (z-a)^2)^{3/2}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael you're right, corrected the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z$ for which $f'(z) = 0$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial
$$4 z^{10}+\left(20 a^{2}+15 a \right) z^{8}+\left(-24 a^{4}+20 a^{3}+20 a^{2}\right) z^{6}+\left(-24 a^{6}-70 a^{5}-20 a^{4}+10 a^{3}\right) z^{4}+\left(20 a^{8}+20 a^{7}-20 a^{6}-20 a^{5}\right) z^{2}+4 a^{10}+15 a^{9}+20 a^{8}+10 a^{7}-a^{5}$$
The quintic obtained by substituting $t$ for $z^2$ has Galois group $S_5$ for
typical values of $a$.
So you're not going to get a solution expressible in terms of radicals.

For particular values of $a$ you can solve it numerically.